# Move all InnoDB databases into one subdirectory (innodb_file_per_table is ON)

Tags: mysql, innodb

First of all, excuse my English.

I want to run a MySQL 5.6 on ZFS volume, and need to move all InnoDB databases to one subdirectory (which in fact will be a different ZFS filesystem). For example, by default mysql/ directory look like:

```
mysql/
mysql/my.cnf
mysql/ib_logfile0
mysql/ib_logfile1
mysql/ibdata1
mysql/database1/
mysql/database2/
...
```

and I want to make it like:

```
mysql/
mysql/my.cnf
mysql/ib_logfile0
mysql/ib_logfile1
mysql/db/ibdata1
mysql/db/database1/
mysql/db/database2/
...
```

Is it possible?